# What does FFmpeg do when run without options?

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4

I downloaded a few MP4 video files that seemed ridiculously large for their length and resolution. So to try to decrease their size, I ran the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

It took some time, but when the command was done, I had a file `output.mp4` whose size was about just one third of the size of the original file `input.mp4`. I opened both files in VLC expecting to see some difference, perhaps a decrease in quality, but it seemed to me like their content was exactly identical.

What I’d like to know is what exactly does that peculiar command do, and why did it yield such unforeseen results?

Comment: Can you add sources from your own research on this topic and detail why it wasn't sufficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What I’d like to know is what exactly does that peculiar command do, and why did it yield such unforeseen results?

It basically just converts it to a new file with the format based on the file extension. The settings used are the default settings for everything; sound, audio, etc…

As for the file size being smaller, while you state that you see video of the same quality when converting one MP4 video to another, the bitrate is most likely lowered in some way for the video as well as audio.

The higher the bitrate the more data the file contains and — as a result — a higher quality video.

You might not visually see a difference, but check the underlying specs of the source video versus the converted video and I am fairly certain you will see higher bitrate in the source for audio and video.

Comment: And if the file extensions are the same?

Comment: @nc404 Updated my answer: You might not visually see a difference, but the bitrate of the source is most likely higher than the derivative output video.

Comment: I see. You are correct. The bitrate is lowered in the output file by about the amount that the size of the file is lowered. What is the bitrate tho? Does it have to do with the frame rate?

Comment: If the bitrate went down so dramatically (from 6791240 to 2449288), shouldn't the quality have gone down dramatically as well, at least noticeably?

Comment: Bitrate is basically how much data is associated with the data flowing from the video. Framerate is how many frames per second there are while bitrate is how much data is associated with each frame. Higher bitrate equals more data. More data means higher quality. As for why you are not seeing a difference in quality, it might be fine for your small computer screen. But if you were to play it back on a larger TV screen then you might see artifacts and loss of quality.

Answer (score 0):

## How ffmpeg made a much smaller file that still looks good

The answer depends on several factors:

- The format of the input and the encoder used to create it.
- The format of the output which determines which encoders are picked.
- Available encoders are determined how your `ffmpeg` is configured.
- The encoders themselves have default settings. The default settings can vary between different encoders.
- File size is also determined by the number of input and output streams. The default [stream selection](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) behavior only chooses one stream per type. So if your input has 2 audio streams it will choose only 1 unless you manually choose streams with `-map`.
- How you perceive quality. What looks good to you may not look as good to others.

## MP4 specifically

For the vast majority of users the default encoders for MP4 are:

- *libx264* - H.264 video encoder.
- *aac* - The built-in FFmpeg AAC encoder.

x264 does not choose a specific bitrate for rate control. It chooses a default CRF level which controls quality. The default is `-crf 23` which is a good compromise between quality and file size. See [FFmpeg Wiki: H.264](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264) for more info.

Not all formats are equal, and not all encoders are equal. H.264 is showing its age, but it is still a good format. x264 is the most efficient H.264 encoder. So if you give x264 an input that was created by a crappy or inefficient encoder–or an old, legacy format–then it will reduce the file size (sometimes significantly) without terrible [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss).

#### Seeing which encoders are being used

You can find out which encoders are being used by the console output from your command:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input.mkv output.mp4
  …
  Stream mapping:
    Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (ffv1 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
    Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (flac (native) -> aac (native))
```

In this example you can see *libx264* and *aac* are the encoders used to create the output.